# Determining location of a Point3d on a grid with defined regions

Tags: c#, .net

I have a xy plane containing a series of alphabetically named non-overlapping rectangular regions defined by 2 corners each as Point3d's (z-dimension is immaterial here, they are outputted by api as point3ds).

How can I best find which region a random point3d lays within?

Also, how could I check to make sure the regions are infact not overlapping?

Thanks!

Comment: Please show the relevant code - otherwise it's a little difficult to provide a good answer without knowing what your objects look like. How is "a xy plane" defined? What is a `Point3d`?

Comment: When you ask "how can I make sure the regions are not overlapping?", you would have to do that before adding a region (in the `Add` method, check if `Regions.Any(region => region.Overlaps(candidateRegion))`. This assumes you have a `Region` class that contains two `Point3d` properties and an `Overlaps(Region other)` method. It would be helpful if you showed the `Region` class.

Comment: What does "alphabetically-named" mean, and how does that information impact the answer? Is there some sorting or ordering involved regarding the `Name` property?

Comment: Sounds like your regions are just axis-aligned bounding boxes (AABBs). The "best" way to find intersections / collisions will depend on the size of your data set and how close things are. A brute force search might be good enough. If not, quad trees are another common solution, but we'd need to know more about your data. Collision detection is a common task in UI and game libraries, so there's a lot of code and techniques available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without code to represent your objects, it's a little difficult to answer, but here's an example using a `Region` struct that contains two `Point` properties (which I assume are similar to your `Point3d` classes except there's no `Z`, which you said is irrelevant).

First, I would include a property that represents the region as a `Rectangle`, since it has most of the functionality you already need. I would also include methods that tell you if a `Region` contains a `Point`, if one `Region` instance overlaps another `Region`, and a method that tells you if any `Region` in a list overlaps another in the list:

```
public struct Region
{
    public Point Corner1 { get; }

    public Point Corner2 { get; }

    public Rectangle Rectangle { get; }

    public Region(Point corner1, Point corner2)
    {
        Corner1 = corner1;
        Corner2 = corner2;
        var leftMost = Math.Min(Corner1.X, Corner2.X);
        var topMost = Math.Min(Corner1.Y, Corner2.Y);
        var width = Math.Abs(Corner1.X - Corner2.X);
        var height = Math.Abs(Corner1.Y - Corner2.Y);
        Rectangle = new Rectangle(leftMost, topMost, width, height);
    }

    public static bool AnyOverlap(List<Region> regions)
    {
        if (regions == null || regions.Count == 1) return false;

        for (int i = 0; i < regions.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < regions.Count; j++)
            {
                if (regions[i].Overlaps(regions[j]))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public bool Contains(Point p)
    {
        return p.X >= Rectangle.Left && p.X <= Rectangle.Right &&
               p.Y >= Rectangle.Top && p.Y <= Rectangle.Bottom;
    }

    public bool Overlaps(Region other)
    {
        return Rectangle.Left < other.Rectangle.Right &&
               Rectangle.Right > other.Rectangle.Left &&
               Rectangle.Top > other.Rectangle.Bottom &&
               Rectangle.Bottom < other.Rectangle.Top;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return obj is Region && Rectangle.Equals(((Region) obj).Rectangle);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Rectangle.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

With this, if you have a `List<Region> xyPlane`, you can do:

```
Point randomPoint = new Point(20, 30);

bool anyRegionsOverlap = Region.AnyOverlap(xyPlane);
Region containsPoint = xyPlane.FirstOrDefault(region =>
    region.Contains(randomPoint));
```

Comment: Is there a reason you made Region a struct and not a class? I'm a beginner and haven't encountered structs yet.

Comment: This might be helpful: [Choosing Between Class and Struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/choosing-between-class-and-struct?redirectedfrom=MSDN)